# Verifying the structure of a field

Tags: field-theory

Let F be a field and $G=F\times F$ Define addition by $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and multiplication by $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)$

Does these operations define a field on G?

I'm fairly comfortable with the addition part, however its the multiplication part that trips me up. Surely $(ac)^{-1}$ exists since F is a field, and $\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{c}$ are each in F since we assumed that F is a field.

Comment: Watch out for zero divisors!

Comment: $(a,c)^{-1}$ does not exist when either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what happens with $\,(1,0)\cdot (0,1)$ ...

Comment: Ah, right. The inverse would have been division by 0. Thank you, what gave you the hint to check that particular example?

Comment: Well, experience (the almost unique advantage of being older than someone else): the cartesian product of any ammount of fields is *never* a domain, let alone a field, because there are zero divisors.

Comment: could you tell me the difference between a domain and a field?

Comment: In a field any non-zero elements has a multiplicative inverse, which is far from being true in a domain (e.g., the integers $\,\Bbb Z\,$ or any polynomial ring over a field)